# What is the color name of this hexcode #6c63ff in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

am a newbie in flutter.
If i want to use this color hex code #6c63ff and #eee7f7
in flutter, what will it be like.
Colors."what" ??

And if i want to write it in this format Color(xofffefddcc)

How will i write it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create Color from hex code just use constructor:

```dart
/*
AA – alpha value in hex
RR – red value in hex
GG – green value in hex
BB – the blue value in hex
*/

final color = Color(0xAARRGGBB);
```

Color with your hex code will be `Color(0xff6c63ff)`.

Comment: Thanks @mol0ko, 

Which means #eee7f7 will now look like this (0xFFeee7F7) ????
And please I have another question
please is there any difference's in using capital letter or small letter for the color code ???
For example: Color(0xff6c63ff) and Color(0xFF6c63FF) does it have any different meaning??

Comment: Right,  #eee7f7 will be (0xFFeee7F7). And it is case insensitive, so you can use either big or small letters or even combine them.